# How to resolve TypeError in formgroup in Unit Testing Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, formbuilder

I am trying to test my forms fields in angular with unit testing but karma says my property is `undefined`. I did a console log on the `formGroup` and it was `undefined`. But when I console logged my component, I get all the parameters.

**This is my component:**

```
constructor(
  private _fb: FormBuilder,
  private donationService: DonationService,
  private formValidationMessages: ValidationserviceService,
  private ziptoLocationService: ZiptolocationService,
  private http: HttpClient,
  private snack: MatSnackBar,
  private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
  private nservice: NService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.donationForm = this._fb.group({
  gross_gift_amount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,2})?$')]],
  billing_first_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
  billing_last_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)]],
```

**This is my Test**

```
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { DonationComponent } from './donation.component';

describe('Donation Form', () => {
  let component: DonationComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
      component = new DonationComponent( new FormBuilder(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null );
  });

it('should create a form with 10 controls', () => {
      expect(component.donationForm.contains('gross_gift_amount')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**This is my error**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `donationForm` property is not initialized because your component's `ngOnOnit()` method is never called in your test.

Answer (score 2):

Try to call the method `ngOnInit` in `beforeEach` like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    component = new DonationComponent( new FormBuilder(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null );
    component.ngOnInit();
});
```

just after the creation of the component.

Angular will do it for you when you are not in a test mode.